# Update highcharts without redraw

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am new to Highcharts and web development. I want the chart to update every time new data is recorded in the REST API. I do not want the chart to redraw every time, instead just add the new data point.

The documentation of the update method is: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.update

I am not sure how to continue to query the data from the REST API and only update, not redraw the chart every time the query is sent. The reason why the chart is being redrawn everytime right now is because  `var chart` is declared in the `updat()` method, which is being called every 3 seconds. What should be done instead is the chart be created once and updated every 3-5 seconds. However, I am not sure of how to implement this in code. I have tried initializing the chart after, and outside the jQuery method, but that doesn't work either.

```js
$(function updat() {
  var url = "https://xpm4zyor39.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/entries";
  var humid = [],
    date = [],
    high=[],
    day=[],
    chanceOfRain=[],
    humid_final = [],
    day_final=[],
    high_final=[],
    chanceOfRain_final=[],
    Itemss=[],
    SortedItems=[]
    var htmlText='';

  $.getJSON(url, function (json) {

      setTimeout( $(json['Items']).each(function(i, data) {
      //Store indicator name
      
      // fill the date array
      humid.push(data.humidity);
      // fill the string data array 
      date.push(data.Date);
      high.push(data.high);
      day.push(data.Day);
      chanceOfRain.push(data.chanceOfRain);
    }),3000);

    //unsorted array
    Itemss=$(json['Items']);
    //console.log("ITEMS",Itemss);

    //sorted array- date
     date.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});


    // console.log("Sorted Days", date);
    Itemss.sort(function(a,b){return date.indexOf(a.Date)<date.indexOf(b.Date)?-1:1});
   
   
    // query send string that we need to convert into numbers
    for (var i = 0; i < humid.length; i++) {
      if (humid[i] != null) {
        humid_final.push(parseFloat(humid[i]));
        high_final.push(parseFloat(high[i]));
        day_final.push(parseFloat(day[i]));
        chanceOfRain_final.push(parseFloat(chanceOfRain[i]));
      } else {
       humid_final.push(null)
      };
    }

    //sorting the arrays
    day_final.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});
  
    humid_final.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});

      var chart = new Highcharts.chart({

          credits: {
              enabled: false
          },
          chart: {
              height: 200,
              type: 'spline',
              renderTo: 'light',
              marginBottom: 100
          },
          title: {
              text: ' Ambient Light'
          },
          tooltip: {
              valueDecimals: 2,
              pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}%</b><br/>'
          },
          plotOptions: {
              series: {
                  marker: {
                      enabled: false
                  }
              }
          },
          subtitle: {
              text: ''
          },
          xAxis: {
              categories: day_final 
          },
          series: [{
              name: 'light level',
              data: high_final, //
              color: '#9b0000'
          }]
      });
      
   }); //getJSON method
 setTimeout(updat, 3000);


    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src= "highCU.js"></script>

<div id="light" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; left:10px"></div>
```

Comment: you have 2 methods with a time out and you're creating the chart object over and over ... refactor your code so you only update the data every 3 seconds, not the chart object... live example: https://jsbin.com/xoyajoporo/1/edit?js,output

Comment: @balexandre according to your code, the values from the API keep getting added to the graph with every call. However, what I am trying to do is add a new point only if there is a change in the API. If not the graph remains the same. jsbin.com/xoyajoporo/1/edit?js,output  does not add a point to the graph instead continues to create several copies of the same graph with every call to the API

Comment: it's your code, I simply removed the need to create the graph, that avoids the redraw ... exactly what you ask. I'm not going to debug your code to fix what's wrong. Your title: **Update highcharts without redraw** my fix does fixes it